# Can you do arithmetic with any size number in Haskell? If so, how?

Tags: haskell, types, casting, type-conversion, infinite

Haskell has the ability to associate `max` and `min` values with datatypes, but can it also work with theoretically infinite numbers (like adding `1` over the max of `Integer`) in the expected way? What makes the `Num` typeclass so significant?

Comment: Many basic datatypes have a instance of [Bounded typeclass](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded) . Some basic datatypes like Integer have no instance of Bounded, so its (highly probable) unbounded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haskell provides typeclasses to express various different properties of datatypes.

#### Numeric Types

Consider numeric data (`Int`, `Word`, `Double`, `Integer`, etc.). All of these types share a conceptual group of operations: they can be added, multiplied, subtracted, negated, etc. Any type which shares these properties can be made instances of the `Num` typeclass.

#### Bounded Types

Types which are bounded in some way are expressed by a different typeclass: `Bounded`. On my system in GHCI with only default modules loaded, I see `Bounded` instances for `Ordering`, `Int`, `Char`, and `Bool`. `Int` is bounded by the size of a machine word, `Char` by the bounds of the Unicode standard, and `Bool` and `Ordering` by the limitations of their declarations.

Double is not `Bounded`, as it is capable of expressing infinity (and is therefore conceptually unbounded). `Integer` is also not `Bounded` because an upper bound is not necessarily decidable nor constant (it is limited by available memory). Despite this, both of these are still capable of expressing the properties of a numeric type, so they are still `Num` even though they are not `Bounded`.

#### Overflow

In regards to overflow, while it has been shown that `Integer` will not overflow, `Int` and `Word` (which are `Bounded` by their fixed-width representation in memory) will overflow without warning or error. On my system, `1 + maxBound :: Int` overflows to the minBound due to two's complement, though this is not guaranteed behaviour. `Word` overflows to 0, as it is an unsigned data type.

Bear in mind that `Bounded` types may not overflow in "the expected way". The Haskell Specification does not specify how `Bounded` types should overflow, so it is left to the compiler designers. Note that the internal representation of these data types is also not specified, so two's complement should not be assumed. Indeed, even the size of an `Int` is only guaranteed to be 29 bits.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much this cleared up a lot of questions. As a side note, how does `Integer` work under the hood? Does it just generate the correct compensation for overflow while still using `Int`?

Comment: It's another unspecified thing. GHC, by default, used the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (GMP), but `integer-simple` is also provided as a "fast enough" pure Haskell replacement. http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReplacingGMPNotes, particularly the references, might be interesting reading.

Answer (score 4):

You have several sort of unrelated questions.

`Integer` is sort of unbounded, which means it can handle numbers of any size (technically it is restricted by the underlying libraries to something ridiculously huge (more precisely 2^(2^32)), and you will not have any problems with it.) So there's no real concept of "the max of `Integer`".

The `Num` typeclass is significant because everything that can be added, subtracted, has an absolute value and so on is a `Num` and works with all functions that work on `Num`. So if you need to write a function that uses one of those operations, it will work for all `Num`s. So, in short, the `Num` typeclass is significant because all type classes are significant!

Comment: Integer is bounded by your available memory and desire to wait for it to compute.

Comment: I am always wary about statements like "something ridiculously huge that you will not have any problems with". Even quite benign calculations in probability can come up with ridiculously large numbers - often a problem in combinatorial probability can have a normal-sized answer that is the ratio of two really, really big numbers. Saying that, I've never personally had any problems with `Integer`.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Hadn't I been in such a hurry I would have looked up the actual number (2^(2^32) it seems like.) When I say ridiculous I mean *ridiculous*!